# Dynamic variables and params name in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, variables, dynamic, parameters

i have this code that works well

```
var name_1 = request.body.agentname_1;
var name_2 = request.body.agentname_2;
var name_3 = request.body.agentname_3;
...
var name_999 = request.body.agentname_999;
```

I want to reduce lines of code by using "For" loop.
I tried this but i got error, any help plaise ? thank you

```
for (i = 1; i <= 999; i++) { 
    global['name_'+i] = request.body.global['agentname_'+i]
}
```

Comment: Why did you put `global` in `request.body.global['agentname_'+i]` ? To access the object you were using before, wouldn't you use use `request.body['agentname_'+i]`? If that's not the problem, will you post your specific error?

Comment: Thank you @dpopp07, this was my error using global after body, when i used your solution it works well. (y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer form:

Remove `global` from `request.body.global['agentname_'+i]` so you are accessing the same object as before:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 999; i++) { 
    global['name_'+i] = request.body['agentname_'+i]
}
```